# Using MID and RIGHT to capture part of string

Tags: excel, vba

```
s = 003021106    
s4 = Mid(s, (Right(s, 7)), 2)
```

I can't figure out why this won't work?  I get "" as a result.

If I walk through this logically, I want the mid of where "right" is located, which is 7 spaces from the right or "3".  Then, finish off the mid 2 spaces, which should be "30", right?

Or

Is it taking the entire 7 digits and going 2 space right of the 6?  I think it's doing this.

Ultimately, I need to go into a string 7 digits from the right and pull the 2 digits to the right of it, which in this case would be "30". Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `Left(Right(s, 7), 2)`

Comment: omg... yes, I feel dumb. :)   Thanks Tim!

Comment: Or just Mid: `Mid(s, 3, 2)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to go at it from the right because the number of digits vary.

Comment: Tim, post as an answer and I'll give you credit. I don't like having outstanding credits! :)

Comment: @Mike: Use the @-notation - else Tim won't get notified of your comment

Comment: @TimWilliams Tim, post as an answer and I'll give you credit. I don't like having outstanding credits! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer:

```
 Left(Right(s, 7), 2)
```